# delegate in swift 3 does not perform view related codes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

In my project I have some delegates that works fine with returning data but I want to add some subview or do any anything in the delegate method on the receiving end nothing happen but the other codes that are in the same method are OK!
My other question is also realated to delegates :
This happens for some delegates. The delegate does not respond but I found a very strange fix on the web and I need to know why this happens and why this fix works!

My First View :

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
    func someMethod()
}

class FirstViewClass {
    //in init or didLoad method
    var delegate: SomeDelegate?

    // THIS DELEGATE WON'T WORK BUT WHEN I ADD THIS LINE IT WORKS FINE( IT STILL HAS THE ABOVE PROBLEM)
    self.delegate = SecondViewClass()

    //in some custom method
    self.delegate?.someMethod();
}
```

My Second View:

```
class SecondViewClass : SomeDelegate {
    var firstView = FirstViewClass()

    // this is in init or didLoad method
    firstView.delegate = self

    //this is in some custom method
    someMethod()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple working prototype:

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
    func someMethod()
}

class FirstViewClass {
    var delegate: SomeDelegate?
}

class SecondViewClass : SomeDelegate {
    var firstView = FirstViewClass()

    func someMethod() {
        print("called via delegate")
    }
}

var firstClass = FirstViewClass()

var secondClass = SecondViewClass()

firstClass.delegate = secondClass

firstClass.delegate?.someMethod()
```